# How install previous version of SAP HANA Client?

Tags: hana

I have the latest SAP HANA Client version: 2.14, downloaded from there: https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools

But I want to download a previous one, the 2.8.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance,

Agustin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous versions are available in the [Software Downloads section](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/softwarecenter) (see below screenshot).

You must have a S-User (credentials linked to the SAP license granted to your company to access the Support Web site).

EDIT: older versions are not publicly available as explained by an SAP employee [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13711415/sap-hana-client-20-older-install-download.html) in September 2022:

- "*if you need the complete SAP Client installation of a particular version from the history, then indeed you need to get it from SAP Marketplace using your S-user.*"

Here is the list of possible downloads in the SAP Support Web site (I selected the downloads for Windows X64):
[image: SAP Support - Downloads]

Comment: Yep but publicly without S-User? Is possible?

Comment: No as explained by SAP employee here in 2022: https://answers.sap.com/questions/13711415/sap-hana-client-20-older-install-download.html